# Citrix MDX toolkit wrapping of an iOS app fails with an "Mach Header contains Invalid Flag bits ..." error

Tags: ios, swift, citrix

If I start the wrapping of my iOS Swift 4.x application with the MDX Toolkit, it will always fail with the the error `Mach Header contains Invalid Flag bits in the application binary image.`

I already checked the official Citrix community but there is only one unanswered question for this topic. See [link](https://discussions.citrix.com/topic/393167-error-during-wrapping-ios-app/).

**CLI Version:**
Command Line Interface for MDX Toolkit, version 10.7.20.39

**iOS Version:**
10 / 11

**Bitcode:**
no (for all)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you ensured that the build setting `Strip Linked Product` of your target is set to `No`?

Comment: Thanks, your tip fixed my problem!

Comment: Great answer! Thank you very much :)